# How to display a length of elements

Tags: php, twig

I'm learning Twig and I would like to display number of elements in html as long as in my table I don't have 4 in length.

I want to display 4 items, replacing the missing ones with the "default" one that says comment area is empty.

Here is my current code :

```html
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="block_memory gray animated fadeIn delay-01s">
    <i class="icon-quote"></i>
    <p>
        {{ comment.comment }}
    </p>

    <span>
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
        <strong>{{ comment.username }}</strong>,
        <time>1 weekago</time>
    </span>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% if comments|length < 4 %}
<div class="block_memory gray animated fadeIn delay-01s">
    <i class="icon-quote"></i>
    <p>    
        This comment area is empty!
    </p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I just don't think I have the logic to do what I want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to say you always want to display 4 items, replacing the missing ones with the "default" one that says comment area is empty?

Comment: Have a look at [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)

Comment: Exactly. I must have expressed myself badly